# Illegal base64 character 2d

Tags: java, spring-boot, encoding, jwt, public-key

I am building a java spring boot auth service that creates a jwt and a resource service that uses that jwt afterwards.

Therefore I created a public/private key pair using:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias myalias -keyalg RSA -keypass password1 -keystore myclient.jks -storepass password1
```

I then exported the public key using:

```
keytool -list -rfc --keystore myclient.jks | openssl x509 -inform pem -pubkey
```

Afterwards I stored the public key in the application.properties file in the resource server:

```
    jwt.publicKey = -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAilGFaGPnAThX75U5w3kd
l+McOglx+wSckiBgvgomO8PkwFX3g8YaKoIsKl4FnBab5o3gylg1X0NEqdadzY/V
4SxCN1ED2y4i55BbHQ2eVAP2fNdsn0kB7GHxJsIu0hlaZSfjO7W9qtOExB4Y9LUx
4UxGckRZFoF8zdtG9gDWgFdRxrWDZ6hfsKTm3aAOhL4GpCafGDiwedM9S6f6HWGJ
BSg+aBFWtafebnei1IRNtnRBvZWND3Etj3K9nqOOwrTs8o9f3fIx5NUd4bHkBBpF
E0IXpkiZKCeLQ3kaEttWwnqUSE2WZKIPfoCc6PNVXX3FVkOJOO5/MPl/RtoOnkqR
4wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

However when I then try to decode the JWT:

```
@Value("${jwt.publicKey}")
private String publicKey;

public Claims decodeJWT(String jwt) {

    KeyFactory kf;
    PublicKey key;

    try{
        kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        X509EncodedKeySpec pubKeySpecX509EncodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey));
        key = kf.generatePublic(pubKeySpecX509EncodedKeySpec);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to generate Public Key", e);
    }

    //This line will throw an exception if it is not a signed JWS (as expected)
    return Jwts.parser()
            .setSigningKey(key)
            .parseClaimsJws(jwt).getBody();
}
```

I get an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d
```

can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong here?

Cheers,
Kris

Comment: you decode the whole key string, which sill includes header ("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----") and footer, which are not part of the base64 encoded key. Illegal base64 character 2d is the "-" in the header.

Comment: thanks @jps, that worked! Happy to give you the correct answer if you rewrite it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had such a problem. I used the following command and my problem was solved. Apparently, this problem occurs because of the minus character in the string.

```
new String(Base64.getUrlDecoder().decode());
```

Answer (score 0):

your public key should not have Illegal character like '-' '\n' ...

your public key is

MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAilGFaGPnAThX75U5w3kdl+McOglx+wSckiBgvgomO8PkwFX3g8YaKoIsKl4FnBab5o3gylg1X0NEqdadzY/V4SxCN1ED2y4i55BbHQ2eVAP2fNdsn0kB7GHxJsIu0hlaZSfjO7W9qtOExB4Y9LUx4UxGckRZFoF8zdtG9gDWgFdRxrWDZ6hfsKTm3aAOhL4GpCafGDiwedM9S6f6HWGJBSg+aBFWtafebnei1IRNtnRBvZWND3Etj3K9nqOOwrTs8o9f3fIx5NUd4bHkBBpFE0IXpkiZKCeLQ3kaEttWwnqUSE2WZKIPfoCc6PNVXX3FVkOJOO5/MPl/RtoOnkqR4wIDAQAB

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKeyFromX509(String signType, String signKey) throws Exception {
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(signType);
    byte[] encodedKey = signKey.getBytes();
    encodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedKey);
    return keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey));
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PublicKey rsa = getPublicKeyFromX509("RSA", "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAilGFaGPnAThX75U5w3kd" +
            "l+McOglx+wSckiBgvgomO8PkwFX3g8YaKoIsKl4FnBab5o3gylg1X0NEqdadzY/V" +
            "4SxCN1ED2y4i55BbHQ2eVAP2fNdsn0kB7GHxJsIu0hlaZSfjO7W9qtOExB4Y9LUx" +
            "4UxGckRZFoF8zdtG9gDWgFdRxrWDZ6hfsKTm3aAOhL4GpCafGDiwedM9S6f6HWGJ" +
            "BSg+aBFWtafebnei1IRNtnRBvZWND3Etj3K9nqOOwrTs8o9f3fIx5NUd4bHkBBpF" +
            "E0IXpkiZKCeLQ3kaEttWwnqUSE2WZKIPfoCc6PNVXX3FVkOJOO5/MPl/RtoOnkqR" +
            "4wIDAQAB");
    System.out.println(rsa.toString());
}
```